# Android 5.x BLE GATT service not discovered, but device is connected

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy, android-bluetooth, gatt

My BLE discovery and connecting is working fine on Android 6.0 and higher. However, on version 5.x devices (both are Samsung - Note 4 and Galaxy Core Prime) I am able to scan, find my peripheral, connect and get the `onConnectionStateChange` callback. All the connection steps work fine.

After `onConnectionStateChange` I call `gatt.discoverServices()` - this returns `onServicesDiscovered()` and then I call `getSupportedGattServices()`. `getSupportedGattServices()` returns successfully but it's missing the specific Service UUID that is on my peripheral. I know the UUID is there because I can see it on the peripheral and my other Android devices can connect to it. I'm logging all the discovered UUIDs and it only sees the `Generic Attribute Profile` and the `Generic Access Profile` services.

I checked the `ScanResult` class returned in LeScanCallback and the service UUID is there. And again, this is only happening on 5.x. 6.0+ Android devices discover the service without issue.

Thanks.

Comment: If theres a way to use BLE on Android 5 devices without issues I never found it. With a lot of patience and effort you can make it work on some models, but a one-fits-all solution for Android 5 does not exist, to my knowledge. Android 5 was a huge failure regarding BLE (and other things). I'd tell your users they're out of luck if their smartphone-vendor doesnt provide system-upgrades to Android 6.